# How to send an email on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I'm trying to add a simple email form in my app, so I can receive emails from the users. I've followed some tutorials and I end up to succeed to send emails to my self in development mode. This is how I did it:

1) I installed this gem: 'mail_form';

2) Generated a contact controller:

```
#contacts_controller.rb

class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:error] = nil
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Não foi possível enviar o email.'
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: vehicles_path)
  end
end
```

3) I created (manually) a contact model:

```
#contact.rb

class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :subject
  attribute :message, :validate => true
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  def headers
    {
      :subject => %("#{subject}"),
      :to => "myEmail@gmail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

4) Edited my development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'myusername@gmail.com',
  password:             Rails.application.credentials.email_password,
  authentication:       :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

5) My form

```
<%= form_with model:contact do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Email" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Subject" %>
    <%= f.text_field :subject, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Message" %>
    <%= f.text_area :message, as: :text, rows: 8, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden">
    <%= f.email_field :nickname, hint: 'leave this field empty' %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "contact_submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This worked well in development.

Now, however, I don't know what to do in production. I already have my app hosted in DigitalOcean with the one-click Apps, which it comes with Postfix already installed. I don't know if I really need Postfix or not, or if I need a service like SendGrid or MailGun, or both.

So to conclude this, I would like some information about what kind of services do I really need. Thank you!

Comment: In prod you just need some SMTP credentials, like you have in `development.rb`. Those you currently have will probably work for a while, but eventually you'll probably need a service like Sendgrid. I don't know why you'd need Postfix.

Comment: When I was searching I saw many people talking about Postfix, thats why I asked if I need it or not ^^ Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

gmail will work fine, just make sure you set less secure for application [here is the reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

and here is the setting that work for my applications probably can be your reference:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "ip_address_from_digital_ocean" }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method=:smtp 
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'host_name' }

# Gmail SMTP server setup
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "username@gmail.com",
  :password => password
}
```

Comment: Thank you Widjajayd :) I end up using Sendgrid but I'll try this later ;)